# Using CSV data in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, csv

How do I transform CSV data into Shapefile in ArcGIS Pro ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of geographic information you have in your CSV.

If you have point data with x and y coordinates (e.g. latitude/longitude) you can use [XY Table to Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm), where you can define the output feature class as a shapefile. Similarly, if you have line data with x and y coordinates for each end point you can use [XY to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/xy-to-line.htm).

If your geographic information is being stored as WKT (well known text), such as if you have polygon data, then you'll need to look into writing a python script that iterates through the csv using a [SearchCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm), uses [FromWKT()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/fromwkt.htm) to read the spatial data, and writes to the new feature class with either an [InsertCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) or [CopyFeatures](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm). This GeoNet post gives an [example script for CSV to Shapefile via WKT](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/exporting-wkt-string-from-csv-to-shapefile/td-p/521430).